# Combining different parts of two rows in a dataframe using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large (>10000 rows) dataframe like below, and I have to combine the rows with the same name by **col_1, col_2, col_3** of **group a** and **col_4, col_5** of **group b** or **group c** (**b** & **c** won't exist at the same time).

I could just find online how to combine (add up) every column of the rows, put not in different parts.

**Original dataframe**

| name | group | col_1 | col_2 | col_3 | col_4 | col_5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ann | a | 1 | NaN | 2 | 3 | NaN |
| ann | b | 1 | NaN | NaN | 2 | 3 |
| ben | a | 0 | 1 | 2 | 1 | NaN |
| ben | c | 0 | NaN | NaN | 3 | NaN |
| cat | a | 2 | 3 | NaN | NaN | NaN |

**Desired result**

| name | col_1 | col_2 | col_3 | col_4 | col_5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ann | 1 | NaN | 2 | 2 | 3 |
| ben | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | NaN |
| cat | 2 | 3 | NaN | NaN | NaN |

Comment: create separate group by then concatenate them together into a resulting dataframe.  make sure the key is unique for concatenation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A bit of an ad-hoc approach, but one way you could do this is by sorting your dataframe by name and group, then split up your `df` into 2 parts (i.e. col1/2/3 for group a), perform a `groupby` and use `first()` on the first `df` and `last()` on the second, and then put back together using `concat`:

```
import pandas as pd

df.sort_values(['name','group'],ascending=True,inplace=True)

one = df.iloc[:,:5]
two = pd.concat([df.iloc[:,:2],df[['col_4','col_5']]],axis=1)

def my_func(df1,df2,col):
    return pd.concat([df1.groupby(col).first(),
                      df2.groupby(col).last()],
                      axis=1).drop('group',axis=1)
 
res = my_func(one,two,'name')
```

Which prints:

```
print(res)
      col_1  col_2  col_3  col_4  col_5
name                                   
ann       1    NaN   2.00   2.00   3.00
ben       0   1.00   2.00   3.00    NaN
cat       2   3.00    NaN    NaN    NaN
```

If i'm not mistaken this gets you what you need.

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, you need to assign  categorical value and then sort before grouping:

```
out = (df.assign(k=pd.Categorical(df['group'],['b','c','a'],ordered=True))
         .sort_values(['name','k'])
          .groupby("name",sort=False).first()).drop(["group","k"],1).reset_index()
```

---

```
print(out)

  name  col_1  col_2  col_3  col_4  col_5
0  ann      1    NaN    2.0    2.0    3.0
1  ben      0    1.0    2.0    3.0    NaN
2  cat      2    3.0    NaN    NaN    NaN
```

Comment: I guess I won't use this approach because I am not sure all group b/c are either same as group a or be NaN in col 1 2 3 for my data, thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way of doing it:

The first step is to sort the values in `name` and `group` to make sure they are ordered correctly, then set them as the index. Then we make a dictionary depending on the number at the end of the column. Then we use `.agg` in our `groupby()` and pass in our new dictionary.

```
g = ['name','group']
df = df.sort_values(by = g,ascending = (1,1)).set_index(g)
d = {i : 'first' if int(i[-1])<=3 else 'last' for i in df.columns}
new_df = df.groupby(level=0).agg(d)
```